# Permission Denial: ... requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, permissions

So the latest wall I've hit is in trying to write to the sdcard with my program.  I'm getting:

```
[2011-05-28 10:00:16 - LatinDictionary] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.joelman.latindictionary/.LatinDictionary } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

As you can see from my manifest below, I've added the permission (I also tried adding it to each of the activities, to no avail).  What am I missing?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.joelman.latindictionary"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
     <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
     <activity android:name=".LatinDictionary">
     <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"></action>
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<provider android:name="DictionaryProvider" android:authorities="com.joelman.latindictionary.DictionaryProvider"></provider>
</application>

</manifest>
```

TIA,
Joel

Answer (score 16):

It should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.joelman.latindictionary"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
     <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
     <activity android:name=".LatinDictionary">
     <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"></category>
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"></action>
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<provider android:name="DictionaryProvider" android:authorities="com.joelman.latindictionary.DictionaryProvider"></provider>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  Note: I also had to remove the permission from the <application> node to get it to run.

Comment: ?? What is the difference between the two?   The <uses-permission> was moved, but it originally was within the <manifest> element and NOT within the <application> element, so why would the order or the <application> and <uses-permission> matter (in xml)?

Comment: I had it outside the `<application/>` tag - but it was at the beginning of the file. Moving the permission to _after_ the `<application/>` tag made it work.

Answer (score 7):

Put the permission line outside the application tag, but within the manifest one

Comment: That should be the correct answer. Also, notice that new Android SDK versions include a `lint` tool to find this kind of errors upfront.